# How can i import p5.js into TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, p5.js

I'm trying to start a project in typescript and wanted to use the p5.js library. Is there any way to "import" the library into my index.ts file, so that I don't need to put `<script src="p5.js"></script>` in the HTML. I'm new to modules. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there are packages `p5` available on `npm` you can use:

Install

```
npm i -D p5 @types/p5

// Or yarn

yarn add -D p5 @types/p5
```

Then import thing you want to use:

```js
import { Camera } from 'p5';
```

Comment: How can i use this in a sketch?

Answer (score -10):

You could add this:

> `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>`, like in here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="your_code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry, but this is the only way to do this, unless you are using an online editor like [PlayCode.io](https://playcode.io), if it is the case, you could go to the left sidebar and type p5.js in [**LIBS +**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDYG.jpg). And to make the editor TypeScript, go to the up right corner of the *editor* —not the page— and click the button that says [**[JS]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDYG.jpg), then select the language you want.

I hope this answer of mine was helpful.